# Reading mailbox messages requires the extended permission read_mailbox in meta api v15.0

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I am trying to get all the messages from my user Facebook page.

I use `{my_page_id}/conversations` to get all the conversations from my facebook but I get an error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#298) Reading mailbox messages requires the extended permission read_mailbox",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 298,
    "fbtrace_id": "AeyIKLKPHOABFKXhzvMF-Io"
  }
}
```

On my right panel in `Add permission` I dont have `read_mailbox` as an option.

How do I add `read_mail` permission or maybe I do something outdated, any kind of help would be appreciated.

Comment: _"from my user Facebook page"_ - please clarify, whether you are talking about a user profile, or a page here. User mailboxes are not available via API any more.